# Cypress - Multiple dialog box One or more elements is not Visible

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have an IFrame with multiple buttons. Upon clicking on the buttons a dialogue box is opened.

The parent element `.ui-dialog` is the same for all of the dialog boxes, but the title and content varies.

The parent element that has `.ui-dialog` also has attr style `display:block` for the active dialog box.

I tried an assertion as below, and the first dialog box is working fine but the others are not working. It gives an error as "One or more elements are not visible" even though I added the assertion `should("be.visible")`.

Not sure what I am missing. In my test, there will be at least 4 dialog boxes.

```
             cy.get(".ui-dialog")
                    .should('be.visible')
                    .should('not.have.attr', 'style', 'display: none')
                    .then($div => {
                        cy.wrap($div).within(() => {
                            cy.get(".ui-dialog-buttonset").contains("Yes").click({force: true});
});
});
```

Comment: When a dialogue is closed, is it just hidden with CSS or is it taken out of DOM completely? Can help but require that info.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have four dialogs, and when you perform `cy.get(".ui-dialog")` you get a collection of all four dialogs.

But `.should('be.visible')` is checking that ***at least one*** of the collection is visible, not that ***all*** dialogs are visible.

So if I run a simple test page like this

```html
<body>
  <div class="ui-dialog" style="display:block">One</div>
  <div class="ui-dialog" style="display:block">Two</div>
  <div class="ui-dialog" style="display:block">Three</div>
  <div class="ui-dialog" style="display:none">Four</div>     // this one not visible
</body>
```

with this test

```js
cy.get(".ui-dialog")
  .should('be.visible')
  .should('not.have.attr', 'style', 'display: none')
```

it passes even though the last dialog doesn't meet the criteria.

[image]

Note the visibility indicator on the right is showing *some* element is not visible.

---

To fix it, you could test **each individual dialog** with `.each()`, but make sure you close each dialog before testing the next one, since dialogs typically only appear one at a time and they "mask" the rest of the page while they are open.

```js
cy.get(".ui-dialog")
  .each($div => {
    cy.wrap($div)
      .should('be.visible')
      .should('not.have.attr', 'style', 'display: none') 
      .within(() => {
        cy.contains('.ui-dialog-buttonset', 'Yes').click()  // close button???
```